# How to test component that uses lazy imported @mui/material components?

Tags: reactjs, testing, lazy-loading, react-suspense

I have a footer component that simply returns the `BottomNavigation` and `BottomNavigationAction` components. I am bringing these into my component lazily, but I can't seem to unit test these successfully...

I am using `react-test-renderer` and RTL.

**Footer.tsx**

```
const BottomNavigation = lazy(() => import('@mui/material/BottomNavigation'));
const BottomNavigationAction = lazy(() => import('@mui/material/BottomNavigationAction'));

const myActions = [ 
    {
        label: 'Help',
        icon: <SomeIcon />,
        value: 'help-centre'
    },
    /* other actions */ 
];

const Footer = () => (
    <BottomNavigation /* props */>
        {myActions.map(action => <BottomNavigationAction /* props */ />)}
    </BottomNavigation>
);
```

**Test.test.tsx**

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('Should render with actions', async () => {
    let component;

    await act(() => renderer.create(<Footer />));
    
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I have purposely left the snapshot file blank to see what it outputs is what I'm expecting.

However, when I run the test I receive an error stating that I should really be wrapping in  which I understand... But the test isn't really about what `@mui` will bring back...

Is there any way in which I can mock these, or another way around testing?

I am even open to the possibility of making them non-lazy, but still have issues with that.